# Jenkins - Running test on GUI with VNC - GLX missing

Tags: opengl, jenkins, vnc

I have a GUI program written in C++ which I need to run Valgrind on. When I setup the VNC server on random display (instance :35) I always run into the same problem:

> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":35".

I've ran this manually and connected to the VNC server and try to run the program with the exact same error message.

`glxinfo` only shows the same error message. I'm running an openbox-session on the VNC and Gnome on the desktop with Nvidia's proprietary driver.

I'm currently running Fedora 24 on 4.7.9.

Do you guys know how to solve this problem? I've even tried to run the application with `vglrun -d :35 ./application` with the following error:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":35".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":35".
[VGL] ERROR: in glXGetConfig--
[VGL]    1071: Could not obtain RGB visual on the server suitable for off-screen rendering
```

Running `nvidia-smi` displays the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.44                 Driver Version: 367.44                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 760     Off  | 0000:03:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 29%   44C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    308MiB /  1998MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What is the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: Is Fedora's version of Debian's [`libgl1-mesa-swx11`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libgl1-mesa-swx11) installed?

Comment: @genpfault yes!